# Storing the width of the screen in a variable and how to use it in html and css

Tags: php, javascript, html

what i want is to build a very flexible site for personal use. Actually, i have this in my browser.[image]This will be my start page. The problem is that i have set a container at a width of 70%. How exactly can i set the font-size and the gaps between the words to an x% of the width of the container?I think the answer is relative to the javascript but can i have a little help?Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code to work with? Can you throw the HTML you have in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please help me on how to throw the HTML!Thanks very much

Comment: @Wex Is this link working for you? http://jsfiddle.net/FfdDL/

Comment: Yep! Just append `/show` to the URL and you'll be able to view it fullscreen! http://jsfiddle.net/FfdDL/show/ (Keep in mind that you need to hit *Update* in order for the fullscreen version to show the updates, and the URL will change when doing so)

Comment: @Wex Ok so what should i do now to have a little help from you about my problem??:-)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I even understand your question. You want widths to dynamically update based on the size of the screen, and have each word to be the same width and each gap to be the same width?

Comment: @Wex What i want is to give a %-size on font-size, container-width etc with one stylesheet.So, i think that i need to pass the x-variable that contains the width of the available browser window in px to the css file.Yes i want the gaps to be relative to the width of the available browser window.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is actually more of a css issue with a little javascript/jquery.  This should help you to achieve what you are aiming for: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: Well, I can see that all of those solutions in the link are using different stylesheets  for any situation. What i want is to give a %-size on font-size, container-width etc with one stylesheet. So, i think that i need to pass the x-variable that contains the width in px to the css file.Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about... Use % for elements and em for fonts. for example: div{width: 30%; font-size: 0.5em}

Answer (score 0):

You should really be able to solve this with CSS, but if you want to go really dirty with js and php, here is what you could do.

1. Your first page should include only a jquery function which retrieves the screen resolution and sync sends it to a php script over GET or POST ajax. The script than saves the resolution to $_SESSION. Once you have the resolution data on the server, redirect the browser to the real page. Your real page should have a dynamically outputed CSS, for example style.php. In this php you should return the correct header saying that it is a stylesheet file (mime) and then output your css with values calculated from the resolution you have in your session.

Ok this is my immagination and you probably shouldn't do this, because it is ugly and has a ton of overhead.